# convert jet-sql access column calculated into sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, jet-sql

how to convert this calculated column ACCESS in my sql server column?

```
([VratePctg] < 0.05) Or (Abs([Amount1]) < 1) Or (Abs([Amount2]) < 1)
```

Thank you

Comment: that should still work in sql server

Comment: T-SQL does not have a boolean type; as such you cannot calculate `OR` into a value. You can, however, use `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` to achieve the same. The rest of the syntax is already valid T-SQL, by happy coincidence.

Comment: @JeroenMostert better change the 1 and 0 into `convert(1, bit)` for type safety

Comment: ok and how would you write it?

Comment: please help me..

Comment: `ColumnName as CAST(CASE WHEN [VratePctg] < 0.05 Or Abs([Amount1]) < 1 Or Abs([Amount2]) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As Bit)`

Comment: I tried but it does not work

Comment: "it does not work" is an empty phrase. You have to be more specific.

Comment: I tried do as you handed me: (CASE WHEN [VratePctg] < 0.05 Or Abs([Amount1]) < 1 Or Abs([Amount2]) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) , but accidentally with parentheses , sql server says that the syntax is incorrect

Comment: I'm trying a correction...

Comment: why -1 :( when I find the solution I write it

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks context, but here is a demo of a computed column with these conditions:

```
CREATE TABLE Demo 
(
    VratePctg decimal(5,2),
    Amount1 int,
    Amount2 int,
    ComputedColumn AS CAST(CASE WHEN [VratePctg] < 0.05 Or Abs([Amount1]) < 1 Or Abs([Amount2]) < 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As Bit)
)
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO Demo(VratePctg, Amount1, Amount2) VALUES 
(0.03, 2, 5),
(0.6, 7, 4),
(0.9, 0, 8),
(4.2, 9, 0)

SELECT *
FROM Demo
```

Results:

```
VratePctg   Amount1     Amount2     ComputedColumn
0,03        2           5           True
0,60        7           4           False
0,90        0           8           True
4,20        9           0           True
```

[You can see a live demo on rexteser.](http://rextester.com/PXHUU9665)

Comment: the problem is that I had to calculate on two calculated columns,
I had to replace the expression instead of the column name.

Thank you